# Use a different .htaccess file depending on the server the web application runs on?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a test-server and a production-server. I need different .htaccess files for test and production. On test I want the PHP 'display errors' to be on, but I don't want that on production of course.

I know I can set 'display errors' in PHP too, but then I have to do that in each script that I run.
Doing it with :

```
php_flag display_errors On
```

in .htaccess in the root folder is much easier.

So my question is, how can I make 2 different .htaccess files and depending on the server automatically use the right one?

Comment: Why don't you just change php.ini?

Comment: Can't you just use two different files? Keep one on your local machine and make sure you don't overwrite the live one with it...

Comment: @DisgrunteldGoat:  that's what I'm doing now. But then you'll always have to be careful when deploying. Should be better if it's automatic, which I already use for database settings etc (config.php that looks up the server name/domain it runs on).

Comment: @halfdan: I can't just change php.ini since there are other domains on this server too, some test and some production

Answer (score 3):

Apache is using a configuration directive to find these files:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

So if you change your development server with

```
AccessFileName .htaccessdev
```

in `/etc/apache2.conf` , then you can handle 2 versions of settings, one for production in **.htaccess** and one for development in **.htaccessdev**.
Security filters are usually fine and defined this way:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

which covers both names.